# WordPress will not delete plugins or install any new themes or plugins

Tags: wordpress

I have installed WordPress and the Admin console is working. However any plugin I try to delete will stay no matter what as well as the themes. Any time I try to install a theme I get "Update Failed". If I delete the plugins from within my File Manager in cPanel, my plugins still remain in the admin console of WordPress. My permissions are set to 7-5-5 in general for WordPress. I have tried installing WordPress in a different directory and that does not work as well. I am installing this with Softaculous located in my cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have some serious server-side/database related issues going on. Generally speaking, if you are in cPanel, or have FTP access you can go ahead and delete the plugins you want to from the /wp-content/plugins folder. Upon doing so this will 100% remove all the dependencies from the respective plugin(s) you're looking to remove.

If you go back into the WP plugin dashboard a fatal error will be thrown by those plugins since they no longer have the core files needed to run, and will automatically de-activate.

Another thing you can do is look inside the database, a simple SQL query will pull up your current active plugins, which you can then manipulate and remove from the database with another SQL query, or by using PHPMYADMIN or whatever other database management utility to have w/ your cPanel dashboard.

Example of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins'
```

There's numerous resources out there which will help you 'hack' your way into the database and extract/remove the information you no longer need for your WP environment. Here's an example of one that does so via SQL queries:
https://perishablepress.com/activate-wordpress-plugin-database/

Comment: Well I went and installed WordPress manually instead of using the built in Softaculous installer with my host. I made sure not to upload any plugins or anything. However, when I go to my admin console the same plugins that were in the previous installation of Softaculous show up again. Could this installer be the issue or is WordPress somehow re-installing plugins on its own?